# Plotting with Facebook's "fbprophet" Python API, how can I hide "capacity"?

Tags: python, facebook, plot, time-series, forecasting

I'm currently playing around with the fbprophet Python API that Facebook just released for time series forecasting.

My forecast dataframe looks like this:

```
forecast.head()

ds,cap,t,trend,seasonal_lower,seasonal_upper,trend_lower,trend_upper,yhat_lower,yhat_upper,yearly,yearly_lower,yearly_upper,seasonal,yhat
2008-08-01,21064.0,0.0,13534.8985798,295.074941086,3627.77638435,12515.7266808,14582.8551068,12328.7743552,18619.6705558,2330.03631841,611.380084432,3802.86997467,2014.50868144,15549.4072612
2008-09-01,21600.0,0.0101839684625,13431.7394718,1438.43275222,4947.87832578,12450.622301,14428.4657678,13422.5289632,19595.7519179,2545.44444698,1140.23960946,3979.38497822,3089.74759767,16521.4870695
2008-10-01,21966.0,0.0200394218134,13331.908077,1834.90809248,4653.4289911,12382.4033864,14294.8653737,13411.0205974,19818.8904872,2886.28927049,1512.9361508,4269.31963345,3230.24309437,16562.1511714
2008-11-01,14387.0,0.030223390276,13228.7489691,-3351.95070458,-496.310787437,12312.4002068,14162.0170017,8077.85318805,14293.8736792,-2139.69062288,-3514.21626125,-943.144422123,-1895.13014899,11333.6188201
2008-12-01,12377.0,0.0400788436268,13126.5256588,-5241.07039645,-2399.13703352,12246.8937196,14031.1107877,6254.36024438,12626.4645414,-4278.57816444,-5379.58985709,-3176.14935573,-3734.27501375,9392.25064509
```

This is fine for plotting the simple plot with capacity as a dotted line.

My problem, however, is that if I plot the components

```
model.plot_components(forecast).show()
```

[see my components_plot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21052451/plot_components.jpg)

I still get the dotted line of capacity on top of the annual trend line (which is not relevant at all).

My work-around is to delete the column "**cap**" from the dataframe before plotting.

```
del forecast['cap']
```

Isn't there a less destructive way to proceed to plot the trends without the capacity?

Comment: I'm sure you thought of ```forecast.plot(y="trend")```?

Comment: I hadn't, so had a look at it.

The curve is ok, but it's much less informative than the `plot_components`, where you have the trend, the yearly and the daily, plus confidence intervals, together with the right x axis.

I just don't understand what the `cap` is doing on that plot.

Comment: I think that `cap` is meant as an asymptote for data modelled by logistic growth. Your `cap` is very variable - does your data really come from something with logistic growth?

Comment: No, it's not. I've used it in the way it's described on Prophet's github page:

"When forecasting growth, there is usually some maximum achievable point: total market size, total population size, etc. This is called the carrying capacity, and the forecast should saturate at this point."

My cap is the maximum capacity of my market, so it doesn't come from a logistic growth, it's basic market information.

Comment: It's just really unusual that your cap fluctuates up and down so much. Try a toy example where the cap is constant, or slowly trending up or down eg as an estimate of market size would be. Then cap will look quite natural when plotted with trend.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. A constant cap could be interesting in the case of a trend, but I'm providing it for real data (and it behaves fine on the forecast plot: [see plot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21052451/plot.jpg). It just doesn't make sense to keep showing this on the plot_components.

Comment: Okay. The last thing I'll offer then is that if you don't have logistic growth model then why not specify "linear" to prophet. You'll get a piecewise linear fit and there will be no need or sense in specifying cap.